# GMap.Net cache only mode doesn't really care about the cache path I specify

Tags: offline-caching, gmap.net

This is my code:

```
    gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleTerrainMap;
    gMapControl1.Manager.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.CacheOnly;
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\Data.gmdb";
   var fileExists = File.Exists(filePath);  //this is true
   var outcome = gMapControl1.Manager.ImportFromGMDB(filePath);  //this is true as well

    gMapControl1.MinZoom = 0;
    gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 24;
    gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;
    gMapControl1.ShowCenter = false;
```

However, when I step through the code via a debugger, I see that `gMapControl1.Manager.PrimaryCache.CacheLocation` is still `%appdata%Local\GMap.NET` ( I think this is the default cache location), and `gMapControl1.Manager.SecondaryCache` is `null`.

I cannot find my cache path registered anywhere in GMap.net. Any idea why?

It seems that `ImportFromGMDB` isn't really functioning as it should.

Comment: The call in question calls [this](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/e17442fa6d35b2340ad0deae5efa9ea7d7569028/GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET.CacheProviders/SQLitePureImageCache.cs#L519), you could check what is trying to be set and investigate from there.

Answer (score 0):

To use the **CacheOnly** Mode you have to set the **CacheLocation** property which is the directory that GMap will Read\Write Cached\New tiles.

```
gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleTerrainMap;
gMapControl1.Manager.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.CacheOnly;
gMapControl1.CacheLocation = "[Cache_Directory]";
```

***[Cache_Directory]**: can be any directory you want, like: **C:\Tiles**

Try this approach and the CacheOnly mode will work.